# How to print out the file name that is being passed as an argument to awk program

Tags: awk

I use a for loop to iterate a list of files and at each iteraction I pass one file name to an awk script.

I would like to print, not only the error code but also the name of the file that generated the error.

Something like : print error";"THENAMEOF_THE_FILE >> file.txt;

The awk script would look like this:

```
awk ' function errorManager(error)
{
print error >> file.txt;
}
BEGIN {error1="ERROR CODE X"}
{if (NR==1)
if(length($0) != 10)
{
errorManager(error1)
}
}
END{print "STOP"}' $1
```

Comment: According to the manpage, it's the variable `FILENAME` (Though I don't know if that's a gawk specific thing or not)

Comment: It is not gawk specific, it is the same in all awks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
awk '
function errorManager(idx,    errorArr, error) {
    errorArr[1] = "ERROR CODE X"
    error = (idx in errorArr ? errorArr[idx] : "Unspecified Error")
    printf "Error %s[%d]: %s\n", FILENAME, FNR, error | "cat>&2"
}
NR==1 {
    if ( length($0) != 10 ) {
        errorManager(1)
    }
}
END{ print "STOP" }
' "$1" 2>"file.txt"
```